# File writing does not happen when it is supposed to happen in the program flow

Tags: python

This is not a new problem for me. From C to PERL to Python on Windows Mobile, Windows XP and other Windows versions this problem persists and f**ks my nerves.

Now in my latest script it again happens. 
To be more concrete: I have coded in Python a trivial script. Now the script writes correctly to the file when run from the debugger, but out of the debugger it does not work correctly.
It does not write to file when it should. 
I am using python 2.6 with eclipse and pydev.

This is the code

```
import httplib2
import thread

ht = httplib2.Http();
list = []
k = 0

def check(proxy, port):
    global list
    global k
    try:
        head = ht.request(proxy, 'HEAD')
    except:
        return
    k = k + 1
    list.append(proxy)
    list.append(port)


def OnListCaller(ProxyList, OutFile, NListLen):
    global list
    global k
    filei = open(ProxyList, 'r')
    fileo = open(OutFile, 'a')

    while 1:
        proxy = filei.readline()
        if not proxy: continue
        port = filei.readline()

        proxy = proxy.rstrip()
        port = port.rstrip()

        thread.start_new(check, (proxy, port,))

        if k >= NListLen:
            for t in list:
                fileo.write(t + "\n")
            list = []
            fileo.close()
            fileo = open(OutFile, 'a')
            k = 0


OnListCaller('C:\proxy\input.txt', 'C:\proxy\checked.txt', 1)
```

The problem is in the OnListCaller at the if k>=NListLen.
The file should be updated when k is >= then a given value.
Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Post the code that causes the problem

Comment: @radium, if nothing else, do not use backslashes like that.  Either use a raw string (prefix with r as in `r'c:\proxy...'` or use forward slashes, which will work almost everywhere in Windows.  If your filename started with "t", you'd have a tab (`\t`) instead of a backslash-t there...

Comment: @Peter
Sorry bad me. I always use '/' in perl.
Those were just copy-pastes from windows explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the code:
It looks like the actual problem is one relating to threads, not to files:

Whilst you are executing this code:

```
    for t in list:
        fileo.write(t + "\n")
    list = []
    fileo.close()
    fileo = open(OutFile, 'a')
    k = 0
```

`list` is being modified by the threads you have spawned. I don't know the details of how 'for x in y' works with threads, but I imagine it is missing out the elements added to the list after the body for loop has been executed the first time.

To solve this you need a mutex for `list` which you lock for the entirety of this for loop (until you have cleared the list), and which you lock whenever you are adding an item to the list.

Comment: Oh no... hell I haven't coded with threads for a long time. Yes and the problem is even more complicated, I shall put the answer when finished.

Answer (score 8):

Remember what your mom taught you:

always flush()

(in python, `file_object.flush()` followed by `os.fsync(file_object.fileno())`)

Comment: I updated with what you said before the close() and still nothing.

Comment: see my second answer, your problem is actually with multiprocessing, and nothing to do with files :)

Comment: It is not sys.stdout.flush(), it is fileo.flush()

Comment: @user2599593: updated to reflect the code added to the question

Answer (score 1):

```
import httplib2
import thread
import os
import sys
```

ht = httplib2.Http();

def check(proxy, port, OutFile):
    global list
    try:
        head = ht.request(proxy, 'HEAD')
    except:
        return
    fileo = open(OutFile, 'a')
    fileo.write(proxy+"\n")
    fileo.write(port+"\n")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    os.fsync(fileo.fileno())
    fileo.close()

def OnListCaller(ProxyList, OutFile, NListLen):
    global list
    filei = open(ProxyList, 'r') 
    while 1:
        proxy = filei.readline()
        if not proxy: continue
        port = filei.readline()

```
    proxy = proxy.rstrip()
    port = port.rstrip()

    #TODO: regleaza pentru unix cand o sa fie nevoie

    thread.start_new(check, (proxy, port, OutFile,))
```

OnListCaller('C:\proxy\input.txt', 'C:\proxy\checked.txt', 1)

This is the fixed code.

Comment: Maybe you should expand on the reason your previous code was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you have opened the file with a file handle in Python, remember to close it when finished.
eg

```
f=open("file")
....
f.write(....)
f.close()
```

Comment: or better still, use
 
    with open("file") as f:
       f.write()

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you forget to close the file upon finishing working with it. If you want to check the contents of the file before closing it, call the `flush()` method. Example:

```
file = open("hello.txt", "a")
file.write(...)
file.flush()      // force write on the disk
file.close()      // finished using the file, close it
```

Check you code, not all open files are closed in it.

Comment: I do close the file see in the if fileo.close()

Comment: Yeah. But see fileo = open(OutFile, 'a'), after which there is no close() call. This means, that on the last iteration the file won't be closed.

Comment: I'm not speaking of unhandled exceptions which may be thrown if ProxyList file doesn't exist. In this case you'll just get an exception printed in the terminal and no files will be updated.

Comment: I made the test so the the file should be updated twice so I should see the updates. I think I will start filemon and see what happens.

Comment: I recive the head from both samples but there is no write to file in Procmon. Just a log write after I CTR-C the script.